# Как изменить несколько фотографий записи при редактировании?

Tags: php

У меня есть записи, у каждой записи есть заголовок, описание, несколько фотографий.

Есть две таблицы, таблица записи и таблица фотографии. При создании записи я добавляю запись в таблицу записи, а если фотографии я добавляю в отдельную таблицу с полем id самой записи. Затем по этому id я показываю фотографии в соответствующей записи. Потому что фотографий несколько, поэтому делаю так.

Теперь мне нужно сделать редактирование, и для это мне нужно эти фотографии показать для начала в превью, затем заменить.
Если пользователь просто загрузит фотографии, то в таблице фотографий будут и старые фотки и новые. Как можно удалить старые если их пользователь не оставил, а добавить только те которые оставил и добавить новые?

Answer (score 0):

было

```
запись ай ди 76
фото ай ди 78      фото1
фото ай ди 78      фото2
фото ай ди 78      фото3
```

стало

```
запись ай ди 76
фото ай ди 78      фото1
фото ай ди 78      фото4
фото ай ди 78      фото3
```

в самом вопросе - ответ

удалить фото ай ди 78      фото2

добавит фото ай ди 78      фото4